# SqlCommand with Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I make a selection from a SQL Server table with this code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
{
    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title like '%' + '" + searchQuery + "' + '%'";

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly, but I want to prevent SQL Injections, so I try to use:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
{
    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title like '%' '@Search' + '%'";

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", searchQuery);
        con.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ..........
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I try to execute this I get no results from SQL Server.

Any idea why?

Comment: The title is off- You never set a parameter on  SqlConnection - just in case you are not aware there is a difference between a SqlConnection and a SqlCommand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "why?" is because very few movies have the word "@Search" in their name - i.e. "Indiana Jones and the Last @Search". Maybe "Star Trek III: The @Search For Spock". By enclosing it in single quotes, you are looking for the literal string `@Search`, rather than the *value of the parameter called `@Search`*.

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title like '%' + @Search + '%'";
```

Or (preferably, IMO):

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title like @Search";
```

and add the `%` at the call-site:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Search", "%" + searchQuery + "%");
```

Comment: Gotta love the internet: [Films with Search in the title](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Search&s=tt) - note, however, that none have `@Search` in the title.

Comment: Which I think is a damn shame and shows how little education our film makers have. The @Search for Spock would be a MUCH better title than without the @.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
{
    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title like '%' + @Search + '%'";

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", searchQuery);
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I changed string `sql`, I think that it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use single quotes '@Search' as it works like variable here.